# Setting selectable timeslot in full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I've an app where I want to set what time can be selected. I want to disable rest of them.
Basically it's an appointment app where Doctors set their available time and patients reserve time.

I don't want the time slot not set as available to be selected.
I also don't want more than one user to select same time slot.

I'm of course checking this before saving it into the database but I want to prevent this on Calendar as well.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yep, `minTime` & `maxTime` to set reserved times at the start/end of the day, you can also write hooks into `select: function(start, end, allDay) { }`, where you can validate the start/end times of the timeslot selected.

Comment: Thanks. From the doc it looks like we can not pass an array for min and max.

Many doctors set their available time as 9:00am-1:00pm and 3:00pm-7:00pm. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so in the current version of Fullcalendar. I think there is a new version coming soon which might have that functionality in it. In the meantime, you could manually add an event to the calendar stating 'Unavailable' for those periods of time.

Comment: yea. that's what I will have to do. thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing this?  Jquery?